# Yii2: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'status' in 'order clause'. Can't filter or sort

Tags: php, yii2

I added a custom column(status) to my search model to display OK or NOK based on the values of two other columns.
However i'm not able to sort or filter by that column since is not in the database.

I found this thread using afterFind function:
[Adding an attribute to yii2 active record model that is not in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862597/adding-an-attribute-to-yii2-active-record-model-that-is-not-in-database?rq=1)

I added the column to fase rule of my model

```
[['status'], 'safe'],
```

and added to filter

```
if($this->status) {
        $query->orFilterWhere(['status'=>$this->status]);
    }
```

but still i can't make it to work.

How can i sort and filter a column that is not in the database, a custom column added in the search model?

```
[
            'attribute' => 'status',
            'value' => function($model){
                         if($model->Dinheiro_recarregado != $model->valorMoeda){
                            return 'NOK';
                         } else {
                            return 'OK';
                         }
                       },
            'filter' => function ($model) {
                if ($model->status == 'OK' ) {
                    return 'OK';
                } else {
                    return 'NOK';
                }
            },
        ],
```

that's how the OK and NOK are added to column.

Comment: If you are displaying OK or NOK based on the values of two other columns just use these columns in the query filter.

Comment: @Bizley check edit.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly assumed that `Dinheiro_recarregado` and `valorMoeda` are names of the database table columns try this query condition:

```
if ($this->status === 'OK') {
    $query->andWhere('Dinheiro_recarregado = valorMoeda');
} elseif ($this->status === 'NOK') {
    $query->andWhere('Dinheiro_recarregado <> valorMoeda');
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. That fixes the filtering part. What about the ordering?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN Dinheiro_recarregado = valorMoeda
           THEN 'OK' 
           ELSE 'NOK'
   END as status,* FROM Product order By status ASC
```

> change your query a little like above & then try sorting